# Determining sample size for comparing rate of occurrence between two groups

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, binary-data, paired-data, control-group

Scenario: You are running a comparative clinical study. A test product is being used by one portion of the population (Group T) and a control product is being used by another (Group C).

The Question: If the rate of occurrence of some complication for Group T (Rt) is observed to be equal to or less than that observed in Group C (Rc), what sample size is necessary in order to say with confidence (e.g. 95% CI or 80% power) that this proportion is statistically significant?

Previous Attempts: With the following equation for estimating the difference in proportions between two independent populations, estimates of Rt=1.28% and Rc=0% were used with a margin of error E=2.5% to generate a sample size of 78 per group.
[image]

Problems: I can determine a sample size, given a selected margin of error, but I am not certain what constitutes a reasonable margin for a problem like this. This formula also requires that I presume to know the values ahead of time, which is not ideal. I expect the values to both be near 0 and I don't know which will perform better. Finally, a normal distribution may not be appropriate for such a comparison.

Any answers you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

*Edit Note: Thanks to Bruce for his guidance, as a new user.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a confidence interval it seems to me
that you need a binomial test at the 5% level to see if the sample fractions $x_1/n$ from Group 1
and $x_2/n$ from Group 2, are significant different, with $x_i \sim
\mathsf{Binom}(n, p_i),$ and $p_1 = 0.1, p_2 = 0.2.$

In R, `prop.test` uses normal approximations so
you would need about $n = 100$ observations in each group just for the normal approximation to be accurate.

However, the probability (power) of detecting this difference at the 5% level of significance between the null hypothesis $p_1=p_2$ and the
specific alternative that $p_1=0.1$ and $p_2=0.2$ would be only about 52%. This would
not be useful in many situations. The approximate power
can be found by simulation in R as shown below.

```
n = 100
pv = replicate(10^5, 
 prop.test(c(rbinom(1,n,.1),rbinom(1,n,.2)),
 c(n,n), cor=F)$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.51786
```

By contrast, with $n = 200$ the power is about 81%:

```
set.seed(2021) # for reproducibility
n=200
pv = replicate(10^5, 
 prop.test(c(rbinom(1,n,.1),rbinom(1,n,.2)), 
 c(n,n), cor=F)$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.80949
```

A subsequent simulation (not shown) finds approximate power 93% with $n = 300.$ So you'd likely want to use
between 200 and 300 observations from each group to detect the desired difference in proportions (if such a difference exists).

*Note:* Here is an example of such a test, using fictitious data sampled using R.

```
set.seed(826)
x1 = rbinom(1, 300, .1); x1
[1] 34
x2 = rbinom(1, 300, .2); x2
[1] 61

prop.test(c(31,61), c(300,300), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality 
    of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(31, 61) out of c(300, 300)
X-squared = 11.554, df = 1, p-value = 0.0006759
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.15710243 -0.04289757
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.1033333 0.2033333
```

Notice that a 95% confidence interval for the difference in proportions does not include 0.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks a lot for taking a look at this. Your response definitely makes sense and I think we would want to target at least an 80% power. I am going to digest this and report back.

Unfortunately, my smooth-brain isn't too familiar with running simulations in R, but one thing I noticed at first look is that the code seems to run well for the examples given, but if I tweak them, it starts to give errors. For example, if one sample group expects a 0% rate and the other expects a 2% rate of occurrence, no power will be returned

Comment: If you google online you may find a 'power and sample size' calculator for binomial proportions. Some of them are easy to use and accurately programmed.  No simulation needed. // However, I'm not sure you will find 'sample size' calculator for a test or CI that deals smoothly with the possibility that one of the proportions is 0.

Comment: Thanks again Bruce, I'll follow your advice to better understand the site and try out those other resources. I did find an explanation for selecting sample sizes for two independent samples with binary outcomes, where n = [p1(1-p1)+p2(1-p2)] * (Z/E)^2, so in this case p2 could be set to 0 and Z to 1.96 for 95% CI. I would like to set the margin of error to 2.5%-3%, but not sure what is considered reasonable.